# Post more than one photo - two UIImagePickerController's

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm having a slight issue here.

I have a basic view which has two `UIButtons` and two `UIImageViews`, I would like my users to be able to take two different photos, and these to be attached to their respective `UIImageView`.

Right now this works fine for the first UIButton/image, but not with a second.

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {

// First button/imageview
UIImagePickerController *picker;
UIImage *image;

// Second button/imageview
UIImagePickerController *picker2;
UIImage *image2;
```

}

.m

```
-(IBAction)TakePhoto
{
   picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker.delegate = self;
   [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
   [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   image2 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
   [imageField2 setImage:image2];
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

This all works great but my question is how can I hook up the second picker to a new imagePickerController method so that my user can take two different photos on this view? I know that if I created a new action with the picker2 information it will still point to the one imagePickerController method, creating a second method and renaming this to suit does not work.

Any advice & help would be greatly appreciated.

Jamie

Comment: in the delegate method (`imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`), test what's the picker: `if (picker == picker1){}else if (picker == picker2){}`. Plus rename your first picker to picker1, in other to not hide the instance in the delegate method.

Comment: Great, I wasn't aware that I could go this route with the application but that seemed to work perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two `UIImagePickerControllers` to do it.

Take a look at **`takePicture`** method of [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) which programatically initiates still image capture.

You can initiate additional captures after receiving `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` delegate callback.

[PhotoPicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196) is a sample project from Apple which does exactly what you are trying to do.

Hope it helps.